# How to pass a Component and his value as props

Tags: reactjs

Hello i want to pass a component and his value as a props and use the component that i passed with different values

there is my component :

```
const DropdownComponentImg = ({ valueDI }: DropdownProps) => (
<Img
  id="dropDownImgId"
  src={valueDI}
  width="25px"
  height="17px"
  radius="5px"
/>);
```

i want pass this component like this :

```
<Dropdown
      type="component"
      colorLabel={colors.GREY_1}
      colorIcon={colors.GREY_5}
      value={ImgSrcDropdownValue}
      dropDownList={imgTelSrcList}
      DropDownComponent={DropdownComponentImg}
      dropDownWidth="100%"
      onClick={changeValueImgSrcDropdown}
    />
```

and use it like this

```
{dropDownList.map((item) => (
      <SubA key={item.id} onClick={() => props.onClick(item)}>
        <ItemContent>
          <ItemFirstText>
            {type === 'text' ? (
              item.value
            ) : type === 'component' ? (
              <DropDownComponent value={item.value} />
            ) : null}
          </ItemFirstText>
          {item.value1 ? (
            <ItemSecondText>{item.value1}</ItemSecondText>
          ) : null}
        </ItemContent>
      </SubA>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to pass:

```
component={ComponentName}
/* prefer lowercase props */
```

When you have to use:

```
const { component: Component } = props
<Component />
/* Use Capitalized name for component */
```

Very Good Night!